# How to iterator over an array in Groovy?

Tags: arrays, grails, groovy, iteration

```
public class ArrayTest{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] list = {"key1", "key2", "key3"};
    String[] list2 = {"val1", "val2", "val3"};

    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
      ilike(list[i], list2[i];        
    }
  }
}
```

How to write the above code in Groovy?

Actually, its a grails application where I want to do similar thing above.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have a couple of options that come to mind...

Given:

```
String[] list  = [ 'key1', 'key2', 'key3' ]
String[] list2 = [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ]
```

Then you could do:

```
list.eachWithIndex { a, i ->
  ilike a, list2[ i ]
}
```

or assuming ilike is defined as:

```
void ilike( String a, String b ) {
  println "I like $a and $b"
}
```

Then you can do (using [`transpose`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#transpose%28%29)):

```
[list,list2].transpose().each {
  ilike it
}
```

Comment: +1 `eachWithIndex` is my preferred option. `transpose` is too "clever" by half, nobody likes a show-off tim

Comment: @Don hahaha...  I did smile at the call to `ilike it` though ;-)

Comment: I love the transpose-version. Great stuff.

Comment: @tim I think the last line of code above should be `ilike *it`

Comment: @Don Seems to work without the `*` at least with Groovy 1.8 -- indeed to use `*`, you need to add parentheses: `ilike( *it )` as otherwise you get a `MissingPropertyException`

Comment: @tim That's strange, it looks to me like `ilike it` would be passing a `List` to `ilike`. Is there some sort or automatic list-spreading happening? BTW, you could you please take a long career break so I can get back my no. 1 position in the Groovy question answering league? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/groovy/topusers

Comment: @Don there must be, but at the moment I can't find it explained or documented anywhere... :-/ I'll ask around... And I'm sure you'll catch up soon!  No holidays currently planned though...but June is a busy month ;-)

Comment: I put up a post on what's going on here a while ago, goes into the details of what's happening in the JVM bytecode: http://naleid.com/blog/2008/12/24/groovy-spread-operator-optional-for-properties-plus-a-peek-into-the-sausage-factory/

Comment: To make it clearer, what you can see in the bytecode with javap eventually gets you to: MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object arguments), which then calls invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object[] originalArguments), so it'll spread the arguments out from a list automatically if there's a method that matches the spread arguments.

Comment: @tim thank you very much, especially for the transpose() solution! I learned something new today. Very useful.

Comment: @Ted thanks for the explanation. I didn't know about this feature and prima facie, I don't like it much. A bit too dynamic for my taste.

Comment: FWIW, [virtualeyes found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213247/groovy-list-spreading/6213632#6213632) a [post on grrovy-dev](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/removing-features-in-Groovy-2-td4422494.html) stating that this automatic spreading is planned for removal from Groovy 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what iLike will be doing but from the implementation of your original Java code I feel that you might consider using hash map and your program would look like following

```
def map= ['key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2', 'key2':val2, "key3":'val3']
map.eachWithIndex{ it, i-> //eachIndex() always takes 2 params
  ilikeit it.key, it.value // and you have i if you need it in your program
}
```

Following might be a good reference point for youhttp://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps