# groovy list spreading

Tags: groovy

If you run the following Groovy code, the assertion passes

```
def foo(a, b) {
  a + b
}

assert 'aaabbb' == foo(['aaa', 'bbb'])
```

This suggests that if a method is called with a List parameter that contains X elements, then the List will be spread and a method with X arguments will be invoked.

Of course, this will only happen if there isn't a method defined with a single parameter of type List (or ancestor thereof).

I only discovered this quite recently when reading another SO Groovy answer. I've never seen it mentioned in the Groovy docs, release notes, or books. Is it a hidden feature, a bug, or just something I've missed?

Comment: Might get a quicker answer to this on the groovy user list?

Comment: @tim you're probably right, but the mailing list experience is brutal once you're used to SO. If I don't get an answer here, I'll post it to the list and link to the mailing list post here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going to be removed in Groovy 2 apparently:
http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/removing-features-in-Groovy-2-td4422494.html

JT's first on the to-remove list and it seems everyone (with clout) on Groovy User agrees.

Comment: +1 Well found!  Groovy 2.0 is going to break a lot of things (but fix so many more)

Comment: +1 nice detective work. Anybody who was using these features deserves to have their code broken :)

Comment: that thread is quite interesting, if you read on, it turns into a hijacked we-want-x-y-z for 2.0 thread ;) I agree groovy user is a bit painful compared to SO, but as far as gaining insight into the direction groovy.lang is taking, it is the source

Comment: This kind of beneficial changes are the another reason for me to avoid Groovy. I thought Groovy++ would actually become Groovy 2.0... am I wrong?